# Ajax request using mootools not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I try loading content into a div with [this](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Mootools-12-Ajax-Request_t64355.html) tutorial. Unfortunately, this simply loads the HTML file as a new page.

This is the javascript that should do the job

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

     $('runAjax').addEvent('click', function(event) {
         event.stop();
         var req = new Request({
             method: 'get',
             url: $('runAjax').get('href'),
             data: { 'do' : '1' },
             onRequest: function() { alert('The request has been made, please wait until it has finished.'); },
              onComplete: function(response) { alert('Response received.); $('container').set('html', response); }
         }).send();
$('runAjax').removeEvent('click');
     });
});
```

this is the link that should initiate the function

```
<a href="about.html" id="runAjax" class="panel">Profil</a>
```

and this is the div-structure of index.html. i want the content to be loaded into the "container"-div

```
<div id="view">
    <div id="sidebar">
        mib
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <!--img src="img/logo.png"-->
        </div>

        <div align="center" id="tagline">   
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont really care what script i use as long as its compatible with MooTools 1.2, because i need it for a sliding top panel and it would be a lot more work to change it to a jquery panel for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ' missing here:

```
alert('Response received.);
```

Comment: thats how copypasta can cost you your life

Answer (score 0):

You're making things more complicated than you need to.  Give this a try:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    function loadPage(url) {
        $('container').load(url);
    }

    $('runAjax').addEvent('click', function(e) {
        e.stop();
        loadPage(this.get('href'));
        this.removeEvent('click', loadPage);
    });
});
```

If that doesn't work, boot up Firebug and see what Javascript errors are getting logged.  Here's the reference for the Element.load() shortcut:

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML#Element:load

Answer (score 0):

You aren't stopping the click event as recommended.

instead of:

`event.stop();`

do:

`new Event(event).stop();`